# Images are not uploading on production environment by using Ckeditor + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I am using the `Ckeditor` for adding the content. For this I have used `Ckeditor gem`, but when I am uploading the Images on server with production environment its not uploading, it throwing 404 exception.

But when I am uploading the images on development environment , it gets uploaded and I am using `Rails 4.1.6`.

I am not understanding why the images are not uploaded on server with production environment, I have also checked the `uploads` folder permission and its correct.

Any one has faced same issue previously or any one know the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be use **gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"**. May be it works fine.

Comment: I have used carrierwave